# Не работает обновления useState в React ( ошибки в консоли нет! )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

проблема с React, не обновляет стейт когда я делаю функцию обновления, я обозначил комментарии где не работает обновления стейта, а именно `setActiveItem('main')` в функции `deleteListItem`. Функция принимает в себя id удаляемого элемента со списка, но это не касается ошибки. Проблема именно в обновлении стейта, туда просто должна заходить строка и все, коме этой функции на стейт ничего не влияет. Спасибо

Вы можете писать что вам нужно объяснить по коду, я на связи) Буду рад если кто-то поможет открыть глаза на возможную проблему. Спасибо

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

import AddItem from "./components/AddItem/AddItem";
import ItemList from "./components/ItemList/ItemList";
import listSVG from './assets/img/list.svg';
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks/Tasks";
import './index.scss';
import './media.scss';

function App() {

 let [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
 let [colors, setColors] = React.useState([]);
 let [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState('main');

 React.useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3100/lists')
     .then(({data}) => setList(data))

   axios.get('http://localhost:3100/colors')
     .then(({data}) => setColors(data))
 }, [])

 function addListItem(newItem){
   let newList = [...list, newItem]
   axios.post('http://localhost:3100/lists', newItem)
     .then(setList(newList)) // РАБОТАЕТ
     .then(setActiveItem(newItem.id))
 }

 function deleteListItem(deleteItemId){
   let newList = list.filter(item => {
     return item.id !== deleteItemId
   })
     console.log('1') /// КОНСОЛЬ ЛОГ РАБОТАЕТ
     setActiveItem('main') /// НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
     console.log('1') /// КОНСОЛЬ ЛОГ РАБОТАЕТ
   axios.delete(`http://localhost:3100/lists/${deleteItemId}`)
     .finally(setList(newList))
 }

return (
   <div className="todo">
     <div className="todo__tasks">
       {list.length !== 0 && <>
         <ItemList name='Все задачи' onRemovable={false} image={listSVG} 
           activeItemFn={(id) => setActiveItem(id)} id={'main'} activeItem={activeItem}/>
         <div className="todo__tasks-active">
           {list.map(item => (
             <ItemList key={item.id} name={item.name} onRemovable={true} id={item.id} color={
               colors.find(color => item.colorId === color.id)
             } activeItemFn={(id) => setActiveItem(id)} activeItem={activeItem} deleteListItem={deleteListItem} />
           ))}
         </div> 
       </>}
       <AddItem colors={colors} addListItem={addListItem} name="Добавить папку" />
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Кусок с другой части кода : при нажатии на кнопку `<button className='button item__confirm-delete' onClick={confirmationDelete}>Удалить</button>` исполняется функция
`function confirmationDelete(){ deleteListItem(id); setCheckDelete(false); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

см. комментарии ниже.

```js
function addListItem(newItem) {
  let newList = [...list, newItem];
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3100/lists", newItem)
    // Неправильная запись. then принимает callback функцию, а вы передаете результат вызовы ф-ции
    /*.then(setList(newList)) 
      .then(setActiveItem(newItem.id));*/
    .then(() => {
      setList(newList)
      setList(newList)
      setActiveItem(newItem.id)
    })
}

function deleteListItem(deleteItemId) {
  let newList = list.filter((item) => {
    return item.id !== deleteItemId;
  });
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:3100/lists/${deleteItemId}`)
    //опять результат передаете
    /*.finally(setList(newList));*/
    .then(() => {
      setList(newList);
      setActiveItem("main"); // сюда правильней перенести
    });
}
```

Comment: 1. Добрый день, спасибо за ответ. При вызове функции deleteListItem() activeItem уже не main , а id элемента ( на скриншоте обозначено красным) (скриншот - https://prnt.sc/ZxoVmpCOjXcp ) . После нажатия на крестик -> потом на кнопку удалить происходит вызов функции где и должен поменяться activeItem, но... посмотрите на скриншот ( скриншот - https://prnt.sc/b2CpMiS4kMaz )

2. Тут проблемы нет . Попробовал ваш вариант, работает так же) Но стейт все равно не меняется(

Comment: прикрепите компоненты в которых происходит вызов `addListItem`, `deleteListItem`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-fire-c5f9js?file=/src/App.js:0-2064

Comment: Я решил эту проблему добавив useEffect, но вам не кажется такой метод костыльный? И почему все таки не работает прямой вызов? НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ( скриншот 1 : https://prnt.sc/fBCZEkB3Hyns ) ( скриншот 2 : https://prnt.sc/aOzM_7lVcFJL )

Comment: Да, костыль + у вас ошибки по коду еще есть. Обновлю ответ.

Comment: Поработайте над кодом своим, постарайтесь упростить, т.к. у вас гора пропсов передается потомкам. Запросы к серверу имеет смысл вынести в отдельный хук и т.п.  + `ItemList`, который вы назначаете как `main`, скорей всего, лучше сделать как отдельный компонент, чтобы не перекидывать туда-сюда лишние пропсы. У вас в 1 компоненте 3 стейта, повод задуматься, на правильном ли вы пути, возможно, лучше применить Контекст?

Comment: Спасибо, я только начинаю. Это приложение в рамках моей обучающей программы. Я не сильно опытен еще. Но стараюсь развиваться, веду свой блог в инстаграм и телеграмм, если будет интересно можете наблюдать за мной ( ссылка: https://www.instagram.com/react.ru и https://t.me/react1ru ) . Говорят что лучше пользоваться Redux. Сейчас буду его изучать и потом переделаю приложение. Спасибо вам за подсказки, я учту все ваши замечания, и спасибо, что откликнулись в решении этой проблемы!!!

Comment: Все работает! СПАСИБО!